# change color when the number goes down

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the class name to an element when its value goes down

My view in the blade is a `foreach`

```
@foreach ($scaduti as $item )
    <tr>
       <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->lotto}}</td>
       <td>{{carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $item->data_di_scadenza)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->sector->settore}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->sector->scaffale}}</td>
       <td id="changecolor">{{$item->sector->quantita_rimanente - $item->sector->quantita_bloccata}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->sector->quantita_bloccata}}</td>


    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

I want to add a class to the `td` with id "changecolor"

My script is:

```
var x = document.getElementById("changecolor").innerHTML;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i] <= 20){
         document.getElementById('changecolor').className= 'changetored';
        }

}
```

The color is applied only to the first element of the `foreach` and ignoring all the others.

I want to apply it to all `foreach` results that respect the if

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementById will always give you a single element. Most of the time the first element that it finds.

Instead of giving each element same id give them same name like

```
<td name="changecolor">{{$item->sector->quantita_rimanente - $item->sector->quantita_bloccata}}</td>
```

then use : `document.getElementsByName("changecolor")`

This will give all the elements with name 'changecolor'.

You can loop through these elements and do the thing you want.

Your modified code will look something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("changecolor");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].innerHTML <= 20){
         x[i].className = "changetored";
        }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this seems to have solved the problem

Comment: Hi @alessioscionti if it works for you, you can accept the answer to stop new answers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, as many users said, on id univocity. How to easly solve that? Let's say you have an `id` on `$item` that is a progressive number from 0 to ...

In this case you could do something like:

```
@foreach ($scaduti as $item )
    <tr>
       <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->lotto}}</td>
       <td>{{carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $item->data_di_scadenza)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->sector->settore}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->sector->scaffale}}</td>
       <td id="{{ $item->id }}">{{$item->sector->quantita_rimanente - $item->sector->quantita_bloccata}}</td>
       <td>{{$item->sector->quantita_bloccata}}</td>


    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Then the script becames:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < length of scaduti; i++) {
    var x = document.getElementById(i).innerHTML;
    if(x[i] <= 20){
         document.getElementById(i).className= 'changetored';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using the id attribute more than once. An id should only appear once on a page. There are a couple ways to solve this problem:

1. change the id to a class='changecolor', then iterate through all of the elements with the changecolor class.
2. loop through the s of the  and change the color of the 6th

I would suggest looking up document.querySelector to help in this.